# Remove nullable values from Dictionary and recasting the type

Tags: c#, .net

Imagine I have the following enum:

```
public enum CompassDirection
{
    North,
    East,
    South,
    West
}
```

and a `Dictionary<string, CompassDirection?>`:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, CompassDirection?>
{
    { "Foo", CompassDirection.North },
    { "Bar", null },
    { "Baz", CompassDirection.West }
};
```

How can I elegantly remove `null` values from the dictionary, or copy to a new dictionary, and get back a `Dictionary<string, CompassDirection>` **(note the generic argument of `TValue` is now non-nullable)**?

One solution I can think of is:

```
 public static IDictionary<string, CompassDirection> CopyToNonNullableDictionary
    (IDictionary<string, CompassDirection?> input)
 {
     return (from kvp in input
             where kvp.Value != null
             select kvp).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => (CompassDirection)kvp.Value);
 }
```

Is there a better way without copying?

Comment: You will have to copy somehow if you want to make a `Dictionary<T>` from a `Dictionary<Nullable<T>>`. You can't change the class of an instance!

Comment: Whether this is a *better* way than copying is highly questionable, but you can write a class that implements `IDictionary<string, CompassDirection>`, and accepts an `IDictionary<string, CompassDirection?>` as a constructor parameter. All access to members is forwarded to the stored dictionary, but you could throw key-not-founds or return false from `TryGetValue` as appropriate for keys that do exist in the stored dictionary but are null.

Comment: Well I think you handled things at the wrong place. Remove some values later is more complex than just don't add them before. So check the values someone will add in the dictionary if they are != null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written an generic extension method to solve my problem instead:

```
public static class KeyValuePairHelpers
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> 
        ToValueNonNullableKvps<TKey, TValue>(
            this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue?>> input)
            where TValue : struct
    {
        return from kvp in input
               where kvp.Value.HasValue
               select new KeyValuePair(kvp.Key, (TValue)kvp.Value);
    }
```

Usage:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, CompassDirection?>
{
    { "Foo", CompassDirection.North },
    { "Bar", null },
    { "Baz", CompassDirection.West }
};
var nonNullableKvps = dictionary.ToValueNullableKvps(); 
// Type of nonNullableKvps is now IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, CompassDirection>>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, as soon as you say "elegantly remove null", you're in the realm of highly opinionated answers.

Here are two methods (1 `Linq` and 1 non-`Linq`) that you could also use, if you find them to be elegant.  Nullable types have a `HasValue` property to determine if null or not.  If the type `HasValue` property is true, then you can reference the `Value` property so you don't have to cast to `CompassDirection`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, CompassDirection?>
        {
            { "Foo", CompassDirection.North },
            { "Bar", null },
            { "Baz", CompassDirection.West }
        };

        Console.WriteLine("New Dictionary 1:");
        PrintDictionary(RemoveNullMethod1(dictionary));

        Console.WriteLine("New Dictionary 2:");     
        PrintDictionary(RemoveNullMethod2(dictionary));
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, CompassDirection> RemoveNullMethod1(Dictionary<string, CompassDirection?> input)
    {
        return input
            .Where(entry => entry.Value.HasValue)
            .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value.Value);
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, CompassDirection> RemoveNullMethod2(Dictionary<string, CompassDirection?> input)
    {
        Dictionary<string, CompassDirection> newDictionary = new Dictionary<string, CompassDirection>();
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, CompassDirection?> entry in input)
        {
            if (entry.Value.HasValue)
            {
                newDictionary.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value.Value);
            }
        }
        return newDictionary;
    }

    public static void PrintDictionary(Dictionary<string, CompassDirection> input)
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, CompassDirection> entry in input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

public enum CompassDirection
{
    North, East, South, West
}
```

Results:

```
New Dictionary 1:
Key: Foo Value: North
Key: Baz Value: West

New Dictionary 2:
Key: Foo Value: North
Key: Baz Value: West
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P3dpC8)

Comment: Downvote for this: `newDictionary.Keys.ToList().ForEach(key => Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, dictionary[key]));` This is not only unreadable, but also has really-really poor complexity. Which is about O(3n*log(n))

Comment: @hazzik, I don't think downvoting in this case is a good idea as this is just for debugging. Does `newDictionary.ToList().ForEach(kvp => Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value))` seem better? :)

Comment: And if I could downvote twice, the second vote will be for `foreach` loop of second example.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers rebuild an entirely new dictionary. How about if we don't do something quite that insanely heavy?

```
var badkeys = dictionary.Where(kvp => !kvp.Value.HasValue).Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToArray();
foreach(var key in badkeys)
    dictionary.Remove(key);
```

Comment: Your `ToArray()` call also involves copying to a new array, so your answer is just as 'heavy' as the other answers. But thanks for your input!

Comment: I disagree, an array is a flat structure, a dictionary is an entire tree of lists.